# Excel VBA - Runtime error 1004 file could not be found

Tags: excel, vba

In a part of my program, I want to open existing Excel files via VBA in order to modify it and manipulate data.

```
 'Declaration des variables d'objects Excel
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim Fname As String
        'Declaration des variables de calcul
        Dim a As Double
        Dim numimpact, nummatrix, debut, fin, e, n As Long
        Dim i As Boolean

        'Initialisation des variables
        i = True
        a = 0
        e = 1
        numimpact = 1
        nummatrix = 1
        debut = 2
        n = 1000
        fin = debut + n
        'Boucle de lecture de tous les fichiers Excel
        Do While i = True
            'Test et incrementation des fichiers Excel
            If numimpact < 7 Then
                'Ouverture fichiers
                Fname = "D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP1\"
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Fname & "CFRP1-" & nummatrix & "-" & numimpact & ".xlsm")
                'Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP 1\CFRP1-1-" & numimpact)
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
                    'Parcourir colonne B
                    Do While Cells(e, 2).Value <> ""
                        For Each e In Columns(2)
                            Cells(fin, 3).Value = Application.Sum(Cells(debut, 2).Value, Cells(fin, 2).Value) / n
                            debut = debut + 1
                            fin = fin + 1
                            e = e + 1
                            'save the file
                            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                            "D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP " & nummatrix & "\CFRP1-1-" & numimpact & ".xlsm", _
                            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
                            'close the file
                            wb.Close
                        Next
                        numimpact = numimpact + 1
                    Loop
            ElseIf numimpact = 7 Then
                nummatrix = nummatrix + 1
                numimpact = 1
            ElseIf nummatrix = 10 Then
                i = False
            End If

        Loop
```

I made this code, but a runtime error 1004 File could not be found appears on line `Set wb = Workbooks.Open (Fname & "CFRP1-" & nummatrix & "-" & numimpact & ".xlsm")`. I don't understand why as I indicated the right path and file. I tried another way of doing this `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP 1\CFRP1-1-" & numimpact)` but a new runtime error 1004 the document may be read-only or encrypted appears.

Have you an idea about what is going wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting Fname as:  `Fname = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\NL\Test\CFRP1\"`

Comment: Also:  `Dim numimpact, nummatrix, debut, fin, e, n As Long` - only `n` is declared as long, the others are variants.  You'd need to use `Dim numimpact As Long, nummatrix As Long, .....`

Comment: Thank you all for correcting my big mistakes... But I still have an error 1004 file could not be found on line `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP 1\CFRP1-" & nummatrix & "-" & numimpact & ".XLS")`. For the other alternative, it is working but I have another error on line `Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)`. I do not understand why as the path is correct and ws is an excel object so using `Set` is supposed to work, don't you think?

Comment: Have a look at @Kwakkers answer.  Is `Fname` correct - `CRFP1` or `CRFP 1`?  Which one is the _other alternative_?

Answer (score 1):

This line `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Fname & "CFRP1-" & nummatrix & "-" & numimpact & ".xlsm")` is trying to open file `D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP1\CFRP1-1-1.xlsm` and is entirely different to your second attempt `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP 1\CFRP1-1-" & numimpact)`.

The second attempt is missing the file extension, and the file path is different.  The file path differs at this point `D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP1` compared to `D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP 1`

I assume that both attempts were supposed to open the same file? You will need to correct the file paths - I'm not sure which is the correct one.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that.  Second attempt is trying to save the workbook rather than open it, but is still a case of `CFRP1` or `CFRP 1`.

Comment: I read it as he tried the part that is remarked out `'Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP 1\CFRP1-1-" & numimpact)`.  I didn't go as far down as the save part.

Comment: is the latest 1004 error relating to the file extension?  In previous attempts you are trying to open a XLSM file but now a XLS file. `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\mmLaurencon\Desktop\NL\Test\CFRP 1\CFRP1-" & nummatrix & "-" & numimpact & ".XLS"). `